# Blackberry 10 Cascades - Images inside Text Area

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am designing an application that needs to replace some text inside of a TextArea with an Image. For example, if I enter a phone Number that exists on the Native contacts list, I need to replace the text on the text Area with an Image and be able to add more phone Numbers (the attached image illustrates the procedure). This is the native messaging application, but I can't find an API to do this in Cascades.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is the FlowListLayout but would recommend you become familiar with how Cascades deals with simple lists first. The general premise, and how some form a list can help you, is that each element on the list is display an an object, or collection of objects depending on what type the element is. As elements change in type, in this example from the text entered by the user, to the contact found by searching for that text, the form of display can change.