# Blackberry 10 Cascades - search-ahead drop-down + tag field

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

My question is related to Filipe Figueiredo's query (see: [Blackberry 10 Cascades - Images inside Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764462/blackberry-10-cascades-images-inside-text-area))

My Cascades BB10 App requires a search-ahead drop-down with the ability to have multiple items selected and displayed as Tag Fields. Look & feel and behavior same as BB10 email composer's "To" address field - but with different data (e.g. country names).

Questions:

1. Is there a way to do this using Cascades components / controls?
   (FlowListLayout does not meet exact requirements)
2. Can we achieve this using QML + javascript?
3. Or is there a way using C++ and QML for achieving this?
4. Is there a Component market Place for procuring custom controls for Cascades?

My development is stalled. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. This is a **prototype**. It doesn't work well, but it's an idea. This is how it looks:
[image]

Code (yeah, it's bad. but it should work out of the box):

```
import bb.cascades 1.2

Page {
    Container {
        ListView {
            id: tagList
            dataModel: tagModel

            layout: FlowListLayout {
                headerMode: ListHeaderMode.None
            }
            preferredHeight: 200

            function itemType(data, indexPath) {
                return (data.add == 1 ? 'add' : '');
            }
            function mload(text) {
                myList.load(text);
            }
            function showDropDown() {
                myList.visible = true;
            }
            listItemComponents: [
                ListItemComponent {
                    type: "add"

                    Container {
                        id: myAdd
                        TextField {
                            id: searchBox
                            preferredWidth: 300
                            onTextChanging: {
                                myAdd.ListItem.view.mload(searchBox.text);
                            }
                            onFocusedChanged: {
                                if (focused)
                                    myAdd.ListItem.view.showDropDown();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                ListItemComponent {
                    Container {
                        background: Color.create("#660000FF")
                        leftPadding: 10
                        rightPadding: 10
                        topPadding: 10
                        bottomPadding: 10
                        leftMargin: 10
                        bottomMargin: 10
                        Label {
                            id: country
                            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.Medium
                            text: ListItemData.country
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]

            onTriggered: {
                //todo: make it possible to remove a tag
                console.log("item touched.. yay!")
            }

            attachedObjects: [
                ArrayDataModel {
                    id: tagModel
                }
            ]
        }

        ListView {
            id: myList
            visible: false
            dataModel: mdataModel
            preferredHeight: 400
            attachedObjects: [
                ArrayDataModel {
                    id: mdataModel
                }
            ]

            onTriggered: {
                var selected = dataModel.data(indexPath);
                var tmp = new Object();
                tmp.country = selected;
                tagModel.insert(tagModel.size() - 1, tmp);
                console.log("removing: " + (tagModel.size() - 1 ) + " at size " + tagModel.size())
                visible = false;
            }

            function load(text) {
                var cities = [ "Slovenia", "Italy", "Slovakia", "Croatia", "Sweden", "Norway", "Poland", "Finland", "Spain",
                    "Indonesia", "Ireland" ]
                var tmp = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i ++) 
                    if (cities[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0)
                        tmp.push(cities[i]);
                mdataModel.clear();
                mdataModel.insert(0, tmp);
            }
            function insertEdit() {
                var edit = new Object();
                edit["add"] = "1";
                tagModel.insert(tagModel.size(), edit);
            }
        }
    }
    onCreationCompleted: {
        myList.load("");
        myList.insertEdit(); // insert item with TextField
    }
}
```